# How do I configure my entity-filtering scope for security annotations in the web.xml?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, web.xml, jersey-2.0

Reading the jersey doc : https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/entity-filtering.html I was able to activate the SecurityEntityFilteringFeature by adding it to my web.xml along with other activated features.

So my web.xml's features part looks like that :

```
    ...
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
        <param-value>
            org.glassfish.jersey.server.gae.GaeFeature;
            org.glassfish.jersey.server.mvc.jsp.JspMvcFeature;
            org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature;
            org.glassfish.jersey.server.filter.RolesAllowedDynamicFeature;
            org.glassfish.jersey.message.filtering.SecurityEntityFilteringFeature;
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
    ...
```

The annotations @PermitAll (which changes nothing) and @DenyAll (which always remove entity from json) work great.

The question is : to use the annotation @RolesAllowed I also need to register the roles in the entity-filtering scope as said in the documentation

> EntityFilteringFeature.ENTITY_FILTERING_SCOPE - "jersey.config.entityFiltering.scope"
>
> Defines one or more annotations that should be used as entity-filtering scope when reading/writing an entity.

But I can only configure it through my web.xml and I have nowhere to do the following :

```
new ResourceConfig()
// Set entity-filtering scope via configuration.
.property(EntityFilteringFeature.ENTITY_FILTERING_SCOPE, new Annotation[] {SecurityAnnotations.rolesAllowed("manager")})
// Register the SecurityEntityFilteringFeature.
.register(SecurityEntityFilteringFeature.class)
// Further configuration of ResourceConfig.
.register( ... );
```

Any guess ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `ResourceConfig` *and* a web.xml together. It is not "either one or the other". For example

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>MyApplication</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
        <param-value>org.foo.JerseyConfig</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>

package org.foo;

public class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig {
    public JerseyConfig() {
        register(...);
        property(...);
    }
}
```

Both the web.xml and the `ResourceConfig` registrations/configuration/properties, etc will be used. You can see some other deployment options, [here](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/deployment.html#deployment.servlet).

If you really *must* stay away from the `ResourceConfig` (not sure why it would be such a problem), you can always create a [`Feature`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Feature.html).

```
@Provider
public class MyFilteringFeature implements Feature {

    @Override
    public boolean configure(FeatureContext context) {
        context.property(...);
        context.register(...);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Then just register the feature (unless you are scanning packages, then it should be picked up with the `@Provider` annotation).

Comment: Thank you for your answer @peeskillet , i'm going to try the first solution :)